# Variable defined inside loop in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here is a while loop in Ruby

```
x = 0
while x < 1 do
   inside_var = "I'm inside"
   x += 1
end

puts inside_var
```

Although, `inside_var` is defined inside a while loop, it's visible outside of it. It's totally different from Java, C#, etc.

I wonder, did I miss something? Is it really how it works? Is it true for any kind of loop in Ruby?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. Variables defined in a loop are scoped to the containing function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it really is how it works. It applies to all built-in control structures (`while`, `for`, `if`, `begin ... end`), but not to blocks. So if you rewrite your code using `each` or `times`, it will behave like you expect.